# no main manifest attrinute, in C:\apache\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\lib\derbytools.jar

Tags: java

In System variables i created

1. `DERBY_HOME=C:\apache\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin`
2. `JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09`
3. and added in path's value as `=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;%DERBY_HOME%\bin;%DERBY_HOME%\lib;%Apache Ant%\bin;%SystemRoot%\...`

but still when i tried to execute following command from cmd under E:\dbstore..

```
java -jar %DERBY_HOME%/lib/derbytools.jar ij
```

i get the following error

```
no main manifest attrinute, in C:\apache\db-derby-10.9.1.0-bin\lib\derbytools.jar.
```

Comment: [Official docs](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/ij_intro.html) say the command is `java org.apache.derby.tools.ij`

Comment: Error:couldn't find or load main class org.apache...